# Block web access to dir , while accessible locally

Tags: iis

Would like to block access to dir1 wwwroot/dir1 from being accessed via the net, while allowing it to be accessed locally http://localhost/dir1

On II7

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make two separate virtual hosts, one listening on 127.0.0.1, other on public IP.
Inside virtualhost listening on public IP you block access from all to that directory
inside directory block directive.

Comment: what would that settings block look like?